# How safe is it to use an unknown `_vimrc` or `vimscript` file?

Tags: vimscript, vimrc, plugin-system, security

I do not know if this question should be asked here or not. In almost every language, malware exists. Is the same also applicable for `vimscript`?

Suppose `vim` is running with high system privileges. Is there any possibility that a new `vim` user could ruin up his/her system by using a plugin or nice looking `vimrc` file (i.e., so-called malicious scripts in other scripting languages)?

What are the measures that a new user can take care of before running unknown script files? I know that disabling scripts is a obvious solution to that. But there are a really good number of plugins which are quite useful, even for the new learners.

Again to say, this question might not fit here, but I do believe that security is also very important part of the entire picture.

Pointing to some resources or info regarding this would be very much helpful for the new `vim` users like me.

Comment: Not running Vim (or anything) as root is your best bet. Assuming `$EDITOR` is set to `vim`, simply use `$ sudo -e filename`.

Comment: Just in case you are running Vim as root (which you should not but it can happen), I'd recommend to have only a very rudimentary vimrc in `/root/.vimrc`. I usually just turn syntax highlighting on. The fancier your normal user vim setup, the more obvious it will be that you are running as root.

Comment: @romainl: thanks for your kind suggestion...i hope this is the most reasonable thing the new vim users should follow...

Comment: @kba: thanks for your kind opinion...it is also a very good option to try...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, Vim can execute arbitrary commands with `:!`. It can set environment variables. Malware scripts that are shell scripts can, therefore, be run from Vimscript.

It can make use of complex Perl, Python, Ruby or Lua programs. So malware written in any of these that makes use of only standard libraries could be embedded in Vim.

Even if neither of these were true, Vim is an editor. If run as root, we could easily edit your `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` files to create a new user and `/etc/sudoers` to grant them complete `sudo` privileges, and a `cronjob` to run shell scripts to set this user up.

As with executing random scripts off the internet, there's no *easy* way to be safe. In Linux, you could run in a VM [with an overlay](https://askubuntu.com/a/548712/158442) might tell you what files a given vimrc modifies. It depends on how much risk you perceive.

Comment: Thanks for your help...the answer is quite helpful...while in Linux, it  is undoubtedly a brilliant idea. What I believe now, is without understanding the code it is simply not to use that at all...or at least for those `unknown` or `lesser known` scripts...

Comment: @mMontu: excellent info...why not you post this as an answer...i believe that much info, is at least give basic idea for a newbies to look out in the the unknown sources...thank you so much...you rock!!!

Comment: @Cylian good idea, thanks for being so kind.

Answer (score 7):

Extending on muru's answer, you could inspect the code, specially as the plugin code is usually very short (the exceptions are some popular plugins, but by being popular they are safer -- you can expect that many others have reviewed the source).

You don't have to fully understand the code; it would is enough to look for "dangerous" commands:

1. `:!` and `system()`: allows the execution of shell commands, thus could change your system
2. `:perldo`, `:python`, `:lua`, `:tcl`, and `:ruby`: execute commands on different languages, which may contain system calls embedded
3. `:execute`: this command executes a string as a command, so it can be use to conceal one of the previous commands (e.g.: in order to make harder to spot `call system('malware')` or `perldo malware`, someone could concatenate the string into a variable)
4. `function("MyFunc")`: call function references -- accepts a variable as a parameter, thus allowing concealing of `system()`

You could also try running some plugin functions using `'secure'` or `sandbox` to detect shell and external languages (perl, python, etc).